# Подключение USB модема через wvdial...

Tags: linux

При выходе через терминал на wvdial выдает следущее:

> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.60
> --> Cannot get information for serial port.
> --> Initializing modem.
> --> Sending: ATZ
> ATZ
> OK
> --> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
> ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
> OK
> --> Modem initialized.
> --> Configuration does not specify a valid phone number.
> --> Configuration does not specify a valid login name.
> --> Configuration does not specify a valid password.

Как решить?

Логин в wvdial/conf забил, пароль тоже (beeline) номер телефона есть-*99#

Вот wvdial.conf:

> [Dialer Defaults]
> Modem = /dev/ttyUSB2
> ISDN = off
> Modem Type = USB Modem
> Baud = 115200
> Init = ATZ
> Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
> Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","www.beeline.ru"
> Init4 =
> Init5 =
> Init6 =
> Init7 =
> Init8 =
> Init9 =
> Phone = *99#
> Phone1 =
> Phone2 =
> Phone3 =
> Phone4 =
> Dial Prefix =
> Dial Attempts = 1
> Dial Command = ATM1L3DT
> Ask Password = on
> Password =beeline
> Username = beeline
> Auto Reconnect = off
> Abort on Busy = off
> Carrier Check = on
> Check Def Route = on
> Abort on No Dialtone = on
> Stupid Mode = off
> Idle Seconds = 0
> Auto DNS = on
> ;Minimize = off
> ;Dock = off

Answer (score 1):

Ну, у меня мтс модем, и я тоже читал статью с использованием wvdial, когда хотел настроить. Но интернета у меня в тот момент небыло, поэтому использовал ppp. Опишу по прядку все, что я делал:

1. Добавил пользователя mts в файл /etc/ppp/pap-secrets
   mts * mts
2. Потом надо создать файл настроек /etc/ppp/peers/mts-serial
   ipcp-accept-local
   ipcp-accept-remote
   noipdefault
   defaultroute
   usepeerdns
   user mts
   noauth
   novj
   nobsdcomp
   crtscts
   modem
   lock
3. И создать скрипт, поднимающий соединение, назовем его mts.sh (этот файл можно положить куда угодно, я держу его в домашнем каталоге)

   ```
       #!/bin/sh
       DIALTIMEOUT=20
       MODEM=ttyUSB3 # это для моего модема в некоторых модемах надо 
       #посмотреть на каком он весит устройстве
       SPEED=460800
       PHONE="99**1#"
       MODEM_INIT='AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.mts.ru" OK'
       LOGSCRIPT="CONNECT"
       OPTIONS="call mts-serial debug"
       # Устанавливаем соединение и возобновляем при обрыве связи
       while  true ; do
           pppd 
           connect 'chat -v ABORT "NO DIALTONE" ABORT "NO CARRIER" ABORT BUSY "" '"$MODEM_INIT"' ATDT'$PHONE' '"$LOGSCRIPT"';' mru 1500 
           $OPTIONS /dev/$MODEM $SPEED
           cat /etc/ppp/resolv.conf > /etc/resolv.conf # Передаем системе информацию о DNS-серверах
           sleep $DIALTIMEOUT
       done
   ```

Соединяюсь я так:

1. Сначала надо опустить все сетевые интерфейсы на машине (sudo ifdown eth0)
2. Затем заставить систему видеть модем не как флешку а как модем (eject /dev/scd1)
3. Потом можно запускать скрипт (sudo sh mts.sh)

У меня так все работает. Или я дурак или теги на хешкоде работают через раз...

Comment: можно поподробнее? у меня нет файла pap-secrets, создать новый?...сорри нашёл....а куда тут?

Comment: Да, всех тех файлов что нет можно создать новые в принципе если вы раньше на этой машине не настраивали подобных вещей у вас не должно быть этих файлов

Comment: я открыл файл pap-secrets через терминал, немогу разобраться куда вставить пароль и имя пользователя..у меня билайн

Comment: дайте свою icq или скаип

Comment: ася 631513493

Comment: в смысле не я Ася)))))isq

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на свой wvdial.conf, на INIT3

Такой точки доступа у beeline нет www.beeline.ru а такие есть: internet.beeline.ru home.beeline.ru